# WMS cascading - otf reprojection

Tags: geoserver, wms

I need to display in mapstore the italian cadastral wms (EPSG:3857).
I choose to use wms cascading with reprojection function in geoserver from EPSG:6706 to EPSG:3857.

[image]

Unfortunately, the results were not what was hoped for, in fact the projection on OSM is displayed in a wrong area

[image]

(Eritrea...more or less). Can you tell me what am I wrong?

This is the italian cadastre service (EPSG:6706) that I used for my tests: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php

Comment: OSM uses EPSG:3857 (or EPSG:900913 in older systems) not EPSG:4326 so you will end up with the results in the wrong place.

Comment: I tried but I've the same result...

Comment: I can't get it to draw anything but the copyright symbol when I reproject on the fly (probably because it is calculating the scale wrong) but it is always in the right place.

Comment: Are you using Geoserver for reporojection?

Comment: yes, I don't use anything else :-)

Comment: good! I'm using this configuration: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59tFh.png) somenthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested this I get the Copyright symbol in the correct place (near Italy) but no data displayed (probably due to a scale denominator issue).

I handled reprojection by leaving it in the native projection and reprojecting on output.

[image]

As you can see this handles the axis order switch correctly (6W, 35N)

In layer preview the image is fine in EPSG:6706

[image]

But vanishes except for the copyright if I switch the bounding box and ask for EPSG:4326. When I try in QGis I get the same result with both WGS84 and Web Mercator.

[image]

Since the WMS server seems to be written in PHP I suspect it may be misbehaving, you may be best asking the provider for the actual data and serving it yourself. Or ask them to switch to GeoServer (it's free).

### Update

It is definitely broken - when I load the WMS directly into QGIS I get:

[image]

Comment: If you try to use wms directly: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php in QGIS you can display it correctly. I suppose Geoserver doesn't work properly with cascading

Comment: Using source WMS, I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTFoM.jpg), i'm really confused.